# How to prevent form submit from triggering `button:first.onclick()`?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Every time I submit a form by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, the `click()` function on the first `<button>` in the associated form is getting triggered.  The problem (other than the fact that I just find this behavior odd) is that it is literally a `click` event, indistinguishable from actually clicking on the button.  If it triggered the even on my **submit** button, I'd be fine with it.

The issue is that in this case the first button has nothing to do with the actual form, it's actually in a hidden popup.

So the exact question: Why is this happening?  How do I prevent it?  How do I distinguish this "fake click" event from a real one?

(this is a very simplified example; actual code is using jQuery (in case jQuery happens to acknowledge this and there is a fix for it), but the actual issue has nothing to do with jQuery)

```
<form>
    <input>
    <button onclick="alert('button A click');">Button A</button>
    <button onclick="alert('button B click');">Button B</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Button">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NexHC/2/

Please, no suggestions to "move the button"

Comment: Your `button` elements have no `type` attribute. Firebug tells me their `type` DOM property is being set to `submit` (likely browser interference). Setting the `type` for each to `button` fixes the problem. Furthermore, the HTML 5 spec has this to say on the `type` attribute: *The missing value default is the Submit Button state.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

-snip-

#### Edit

```
<form>
    <input>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('button A click');">Button A</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="alert('button A click');">Button B</button>
    <input type="submit" onclick="alert('button Submit click');" value="Submit Button">
</form>
```

Actually I take it back... the reason is a lot more concrete and simple than that.  Submit is the default type for `<button>` as specified by the w3c.  Therefore, by leaving the button `type` attributes blank on your form, you were making three submit buttons and it was picking the first when you hit <kbd>enter</kbd> (love the `<kbd>` styling on this site :P).  See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5) for w3c info and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WtuCj/1/) for the updated fiddle

Comment: Thanks, this can apparently also be fixed per Matt's comment on the original question by doing `<button type="button>`

Comment: @cwolves Ah, didn't see his comment. :P

Comment: your answer was first anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be, if the `<button>` has nothing to do with the form and is also controlling a hidden popup, then take it out of the context of the `<form>` and place it elsewhere. This would also solve your click issue.